# Algorithm to split an ordered, undirected graph into subtrees?

Tags: algorithms, graphs

I have an undirected graph, whose nodes have some sorting order defined on 
them.
I have to split it into subgraphs such none of the subgraphs have any cycle.
I am trying the following procedure

```
listOfSubGraphs = empty
currentSubGraph = empty
for each node do
    if "node + currentSubGraph" do not form a cycle
        add node to currentSubGraph
    else  
        add currentSubGraph to listOfSubGraphs
        currentSubGraph = empty
    end if
 end for
```

Is there a standard algorithm or better way to do this?

The context for the problem is thus

The graph is a map, with nodes as towns, and weighted edges as distance between towns. I need to convert the graph data into a *.dot* file for rendering.
I want to maintain the relative positions of the towns, in the resulting *.dot* diagram consistent with ground reality. I will do this by using rank feature of *.dot*.
I need to group the nodes such that those with similar longitude are in the same group, and assign them same rank. Adding a node that causes a cycle will be pushed to the next *.dot* rank (subtree)

Comment: At the moment, this question is too imprecise to answer. Split according to what criteria? Can a vertex be in more than one subgraph? Does every edge have to be in some subgraph? What is the significance of the ordering on the vertices? Is "Take each subgraph to be a single vertex" a valid solution? Or "Take each subgraph to be a single edge"?

Comment: >> Can a vertex be in more than one subgraph?
No, I need mutually disjoint subtrees  

>> Does every edge have to be in some subgraph?
No, I need a partition on the nodes  

>> What is the significance of the ordering on the vertices?
No significance  

I will add the context for the question

Comment: >> Split according to what criteria?
1. Maximize size of subtree as much as possible
2. If nodes x and y are in the same subtree, then all nodes between x and y in the ordering should be in the same subtree

Comment: Please place all the criteria in the question. But, so far, you've not said anything that excludes a minimum spanning tree from being an answer: there are well-known algorithms for that.